# Merge two JS arrays using Underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, unique

I have two arrays of JSON object:

```
Array1: [ {userId:"123",....},{userId:"124",...},....etc]
```

and

```
Array2: [ {userId:"124",....},{userId:"128",...},....etc]
```

I want to use something like underscore's _uniq method, but i need to eliminate duplicates based on userId, but i want to keep objects as they are.

I tried

```
var coll3 = _.uniq(_.union(coll2, coll), false, function(item, key, userId){ 
     return item.userId; 
});
```

but i only get userIds from the array.

Is there a way to eliminate duplicate objects based on userId property, but keep other objects as they are ?

Comment: JSON is a string representation. You have JS arrays/objects, not JSON.

Comment: This works fine. if `a = [ {userId:"123",bawd: 3},{userId:"124",dda:5}];b = [ {userId:"125",awd:5},{userId:"124"}];` then `_.uniq(_.union(a,b),false,function(item){return item.userId})` returns `"[{"userId":"123","bawd":3},{"userId":"124","dda":5},{"userId":"125","awd":5}]"` so where's the problem?

Comment: Your `_.uniq` works fine but I'd probably use `concat` instead of `_.union`: http://jsfiddle.net/b6PPc/

Comment: Thanks for all the help, the code was good, but for some reason, the userId property was in another attributes object in my objects. I just changed to item.attributes.userId and it worked. Also, thanks for the concat idea, i used it.